# Are firestone soda kegs still available at scrapyards

Tags: bottling, kegs

Years (10+) ago I collected a fair quantity of my firestone kegs by going to a local metal scrap yard and buying them for about a $1 each.  Geographical area aside, are there still old soda kegs available out there for joe blow to buy, or have all of them been purchased and refurbished?

Comment: I have never seen kegs of any kind in scrap yards around me.

Answer (score 1):

Not *all* of them are gone, but the chances of finding them are decreasing.  The ones that are still there are more expensive than in the past.